# How to do this bottomsheet with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

[image: Bottomsheet example !]

How can do this bottomsheet like this ?

```
BottomSheet(
  onClosing: () {},
    builder: (context) {
    return Container(
      height: 200,
      width: double.infinity,
      color: Colors.grey.shade200,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Text('Bottomsheet'),
    );
  },
 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will give you the idea of how to make a custom keyboard, [custom-in-app-keyboard](https://medium.com/flutter-community/custom-in-app-keyboard-in-flutter-b925d56c8465):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: KeyboardDemo(),
    );
  }
}

class KeyboardDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _KeyboardDemoState createState() => _KeyboardDemoState();
}

class _KeyboardDemoState extends State<KeyboardDemo> {
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  bool _readOnly = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 50),
          TextField(
            controller: _controller,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3),
              ),
            ),
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
            autofocus: true,
            showCursor: true,
            readOnly: _readOnly,
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _readOnly = !_readOnly;
              });
            },
          ),
          Spacer(),
          CustomKeyboard(
            onTextInput: (myText) {
              _insertText(myText);
            },
            onBackspace: () {
              _backspace();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _insertText(String myText) {
    final text = _controller.text;
    final textSelection = _controller.selection;
    final newText = text.replaceRange(
      textSelection.start,
      textSelection.end,
      myText,
    );
    final myTextLength = myText.length;
    _controller.text = newText;
    _controller.selection = textSelection.copyWith(
      baseOffset: textSelection.start + myTextLength,
      extentOffset: textSelection.start + myTextLength,
    );
  }

  void _backspace() {
    final text = _controller.text;
    final textSelection = _controller.selection;
    final selectionLength = textSelection.end - textSelection.start;

    // There is a selection.
    if (selectionLength > 0) {
      final newText = text.replaceRange(
        textSelection.start,
        textSelection.end,
        '',
      );
      _controller.text = newText;
      _controller.selection = textSelection.copyWith(
        baseOffset: textSelection.start,
        extentOffset: textSelection.start,
      );
      return;
    }

    // The cursor is at the beginning.
    if (textSelection.start == 0) {
      return;
    }

    // Delete the previous character
    final previousCodeUnit = text.codeUnitAt(textSelection.start - 1);
    final offset = _isUtf16Surrogate(previousCodeUnit) ? 2 : 1;
    final newStart = textSelection.start - offset;
    final newEnd = textSelection.start;
    final newText = text.replaceRange(
      newStart,
      newEnd,
      '',
    );
    _controller.text = newText;
    _controller.selection = textSelection.copyWith(
      baseOffset: newStart,
      extentOffset: newStart,
    );
  }

  bool _isUtf16Surrogate(int value) {
    return value & 0xF800 == 0xD800;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class CustomKeyboard extends StatelessWidget {
  CustomKeyboard({
    Key key,
    this.onTextInput,
    this.onBackspace,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final ValueSetter<String> onTextInput;
  final VoidCallback onBackspace;

  void _textInputHandler(String text) => onTextInput?.call(text);

  void _backspaceHandler() => onBackspace?.call();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 160,
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          buildRowOne(),
          buildRowTwo(),
          buildRowThree(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Expanded buildRowOne() {
    return Expanded(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          TextKey(
            text: '1',
            onTextInput: _textInputHandler,
          ),
          TextKey(
            text: '2',
            onTextInput: _textInputHandler,
          ),
          TextKey(
            text: '3',
            onTextInput: _textInputHandler,
          ),
          TextKey(
            text: '4',
            onTextInput: _textInputHandler,
          ),
          TextKey(
            text: '5',
            onTextInput: _textInputHandler,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Expanded buildRowTwo() {
    return Expanded(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          TextKey(
            text: 'a',
            onTextInput: _textInputHandler,
          ),
          TextKey(
            text: 'b',
            onTextInput: _textInputHandler,
          ),
          TextKey(
            text: 'c',
            onTextInput: _textInputHandler,
          ),
          TextKey(
            text: 'd',
            onTextInput: _textInputHandler,
          ),
          TextKey(
            text: 'e',
            onTextInput: _textInputHandler,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Expanded buildRowThree() {
    return Expanded(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          TextKey(
            text: ' ',
            flex: 4,
            onTextInput: _textInputHandler,
          ),
          BackspaceKey(
            onBackspace: _backspaceHandler,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TextKey extends StatelessWidget {
  const TextKey({
    Key key,
    @required this.text,
    this.onTextInput,
    this.flex = 1,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String text;
  final ValueSetter<String> onTextInput;
  final int flex;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      flex: flex,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
        child: Material(
          color: Colors.blue.shade300,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              onTextInput?.call(text);
            },
            child: Container(
              child: Center(child: Text(text)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BackspaceKey extends StatelessWidget {
  const BackspaceKey({
    Key key,
    this.onBackspace,
    this.flex = 1,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final VoidCallback onBackspace;
  final int flex;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      flex: flex,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
        child: Material(
          color: Colors.blue.shade300,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              onBackspace?.call();
            },
            child: Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Icon(Icons.backspace),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for you help, but in the example the BottomSheet hide the BottomBar when it  appear. In your example, the bottomsheet appear on top of BottomBar.

Answer (score 0):

Home you can play with style and design keyboard.

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // home: LayoutControll(),
      home: Scaffold(body: SampleTT()),
    );
  }
}

class SampleTT extends StatefulWidget {
  const SampleTT({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SampleTTState createState() => _SampleTTState();
}

class _SampleTTState extends State<SampleTT> {
  final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

  bool _isFocued = false;

  textField(BuildContext context) => Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
        child: TextField(
          controller: controller,
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              _isFocued = true;
            });
            _showBottomSheet(context);
          },
          textAlign: TextAlign.end,
          textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          decoration: InputDecoration(fillColor: Colors.white, filled: true),
          showCursor: true,
          readOnly: true,
        ),
      );

  _showBottomSheet(BuildContext context) {
    showBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      controller.text = "${controller.text}1";
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text("1"),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      controller.text = "${controller.text}3";
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text("3"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      controller.text = "${controller.text}5";
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text("5"),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _isFocued = false;
                    });
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                  child: Text("Done"),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 100,
          ),
          Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 1),
              ),
              child: _isFocued
                  ? textField(context)
                  : Column(
                      children: [
                        textField(context),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  Icon(
                                    Icons.send,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                  Text("Send to USD to CAD"),
                                ],
                              ),
                              Text("View qoute"),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but i look that this example is very different.

Comment: i think it is just missing animation and UI design .